# Getting Specific Info from the webull api

Tags: python-3.x

I want to get the ticker symbol of my positions using the custom webull api, but when I use the get.positions function it returns this big block of info. I need to get the small part of info labeled 'symbol'.

```
import yfinance as yf
from webull import paper_webull
import time
import os

pwb = paper_webull()

pwb.login(username='email', password='password')

positions = pwb.get_positions()
position_symbol = positions

print(position_symbol)
```

Output

```
[
    {
        "id": 10347814,
        "accountId": 4479163,
        "paperId": 1,
        "ticker": {
            "tickerId": 950172475,
            "symbol": "PLTR",
            "name": "Palantir Technologies Inc.",
            "tinyName": "Palantir Technologies Inc.",
            "listStatus": 1,
            "exchangeCode": "NYSE",
            "exchangeId": 11,
            "extType": [],
            "type": 2,
            "regionId": 6,
            "regionName": "\u7f8e\u56fd",
            "regionIsoCode": "US",
            "currencyId": 247,
            "currencyCode": "USD",
            "disExchangeCode": "NYSE",
            "disSymbol": "PLTR"
        },
        "status": 1,
        "position": "220",
        "cost": "5210.48",
        "costPrice": "23.684",
        "currency": "USD",
        "lastPrice": "24.98",
        "marketValue": "5495.60",
        "unrealizedProfitLoss": "285.12",
        "unrealizedProfitLossRate": "0.0547",
        "lotSize": 1
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Do `position_symbol = positions[0]["ticker"]["symbol"]`

**Explanation:**

It *doesn't* return a "*big block* of info"! It returns a `list` that contains one element.

- `positions[0]` would give you that element, which is a `dict`.
- This dict has many keys, the one you care about is `"ticker"`. Accessing the value at *that key* `positions[0]["ticker"]` gives you *yet another* `dict`.
- This time, the key you want is called `"symbol"`.
- Accessing `positions[0]["ticker"]["symbol"]` gives you the string `"PLTR"`, which is what you want.

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying something similar with positions['symbol'][0] to define the ticker but to no avail, thanks for clearing that up!